# Can you set the current Bluetooth profile using the External Accessory framework?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

EAAccessory has a property that lets you specify protocol strings like `com.myCompanyName.MyProtocolName`.  Does this mean that you can set the current Bluetooth profile using the External Accessory framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the current Bluetooth profile using the External Accessory framework.  This framework is only for communicating with Bluetooth or dock-connected devices in the Made for iPod program.  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720568/whats-needed-to-use-the-apple-accessory-protocol/1722273#1722273) for more.

Unfortunately, there is no public way to access the Bluetooth stack programmatically on the iPhone.

Comment: I am trying to search Devices that are under MFI but I can't see those devices using EAAcessory scanPicker method. I can pair with the MFI device while going in settings and pairing that devices.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the Bluetooth profile by `External Accessory Framework`. `protocolString` is for communicating with MFi accessory. When a Bluetooth MFi device is paired and connected with iPhone, it establishes a `Wireless iAP` profile and all bytes between the Bluetooth and iOS apps are transferred using this profile.