# Can CoreBluetooth framework pair and talk to a slave bluetooth 2.0 serial module?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I would like to write an app for iPhone 4s that can talk to a slave bluetooth 2.0 serial module such as the HC-06, BC417, or EGBT-046S.  Is this possible?  Can anyone provide some sample code?

Answer (score 7):

No, CoreBluetooth is for Bluetooth Low Energy. The External Accessory Framework can be used for Classic Bluetooth connection. But to be able to open on a serial link from the iPhone, you need a peripheral that complies with the Made For iPhone (MFi) program, and you need to be an MFi member to be able to buy one. Look at this question for more info: [What's needed to use the Apple Accessory Protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720568/whats-needed-to-use-the-apple-accessory-protocol)

Comment: "you need to be an MFi member to be able to buy one" - I think you mean to be able to build one. Anyone can buy an approved accessory and use it (many are for sale all over the place).

Comment: I meant you need to be MFi member to buy a compliant module. Of course, end user accessories can be bought by anyone. Thanks for the clarification.